# start openvpn as a service ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10, vpn, services, openvpn

I just installed ubuntu 15.10 and installed openvpn.

I'm using the same .conf files as I had in 14.x however the service will not start on it's own.

can someone provide assistance.

when I attempt to start with `service openvpn start` it fails.

any help would be great

Comment: The good old way no longer works because 15.10 switched from upstart to systemd. Here is a [similar question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148990/using-openvpn-with-systemd) to draw ideas from.

Answer (score 2):

Using 15.10 and systemd, services work a bit differently. First, you need to create a systemd unit file at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@service` and paste the following contents into it:

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenVPN Robust And Highly Flexible Tunneling Application On %I
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
PrivateTmp=true
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/openvpn/%i.pid
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon --writepid /var/run/openvpn/%i.pid --cd /etc/openvpn/ --config %i.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then, when you want to start the service, simply run:

```
systemctl start openvpn@myopenvpn.service
```

If you would like to add it to system startup, you can edit your rc.local file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

And paste the following in:

```
#!/bin/bash
systemctl start openvpn@myopenvpn.service
```

Then enable the rc.local service

```
systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Comment: this seems to start it manually... how can I get it to start on boot on its on.

Comment: As I do not use systemd, I'm not entirely sure. I imagine, though, that you can add that command to a start-up script somewhere. I'm not sure of the systemd equivalent of rc.local

Comment: Edited to include an autostart for you @Bmoral